# Computer is asking me if I want to install matrix storage console

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 home premium edition. I have been using this computer for over a year. Today I got a balloon thing asking me if I want to install intel matrix storage console? When I look for it under programs it is there, just waiting for me to grant permission to install. Is there a reason this would appear now after all this time? Do I give the computer permission for it to make changes to my hard drive? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would ignore it.  It is for people using Intel's southbridge to softRAID their drives.

Answer (score 0):

No harm in allowing it to install. Is it possible you installed it or it came with your PC, and there is an automatic updater dwelling in the background that is only notifying you because there's a new version?